# ¿Cómo seleccionar una celda de de una tabla HTML que se llena dinámicamente con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo una tabla en HTML que agrego filas de forma dinámica con JavaScript, sin embargo requiero seleccionar una celda para editarla pero no se como hacerlo, soy nuevo en JavaScript entonces no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo

Adicional también quiero editar la celda y modificar su contenido para después meter todos los datos a mi base de datos por medio de PHP que no se si eso se pueda hacer.

Ya que tengo considerado dos formas ingresar fila por fila como se vaya agregando filas a la tabla también se agreguen a la BD o bien ya todo el conjunto de filas, agradeceré mucho su apoyo.

Este es el código con el que inserto filas y el de la Tabla en *HTML*.

```
<table>
  <tbody id="tabAcciones"></tbody>
  <thead>
    <th>Unidad Administrativa</th>
    <th>Unidad Segmentada</th>
    <th>Num de Práctica</th>
    <th>Fecha de Registro</th>
    <th>Objetivo a Lograr</th>
    <th>Práctica de Transformación</th>
    <th>Factor que impacta</th>
    <th>Temporalidad</th>
    <th>Personal Dirigido</th>
    <th>Tipo de Acción</th>
    <th>Evidencia a Presentar</th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Código JavaScript con el que inserto filas, como todas esas variables ya pasan por una validacion antes de ingresarlas a las tabla

```
var fila="<tr><td>"+unidad_admin2+"</td><td>"+tipUni.value+"</td><td>"
          +1+"</td><td>"+fechaReg+"</td><td>"+objetivo.value+"</td><td>"
          +accion.value+"</td><td>"+factor.value +"</td><td>"+temporal.value+"</td><td>"
          +perImp.value+"</td><td>"+tipAcc+"</td><td>"+ "1.- "+evi1.value+"</td></tr>";
var btn = document.createElement("tr");
btn.innerHTML = fila;
document.querySelector('#tabAcciones').appendChild(btn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mira, lo que pasa es que tienes `<tbody id="tabAcciones"></tbody>`primero que `<thead></thead>` tendrias que colocarlo justo debajo. Y con respecto al js te recomiendo que de:

`var fila = "<tr>`... quites los `<tr>` y `</tr>` ya que estas creando el elemento `var btn = document.createElement("tr");` y lo otro que te recomiendo en vez de hacer un innerHTML hagas un `appendChild(fila)`.

Para seleccionar la celda, entonces te recomiendo que rellenas el tbody:

```
<tbody id="tabAcciones">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="texto_del_campo"/>
                </td>
```

y en el js vayas rellando el input con la variable ya validada:

```
        var unidad_admin2 = "algo";
        var celda_unidad_admin2 = document.querySelector("input[name='texto_del_campo']");
        celda_unidad_admin2.value = unidad_admin2;
```

Aunque luego, si quieres recuperar el texto que vas a escribir directamente desde la pagina tienes que utilizar el evento submit

Saludos

Comment: hola hice los cambios que sugeriste, sin embargo aun no se como seleccionar el valor de una celda en espedifico ??????

Comment: @David de Jesus Becerra Hernand , veo que lo actualizo con respecto a mi propuesta de agregar un input, específica que es lo que quieres decir con seleccionar, los input son completamente seleccionables, ¿quieres decir cómo obtener el valor de una celda en específica?

Comment: justo asi como lo indicas, quiero saber el valor de una celda en especifico poder editarla y guardar sus cambios

Comment: Vale, editarla, puedes pasarle un string o una variable como quieras. Para guardar sus datos y tener persistencia necesitas almacenar el valor en una bbdd

Answer (score -1):

Trataré de ser lo más claro posible..
Hay una etiqueta que se llama *input* lo puedes usar para ingresar datos y además especificar el tipo de datos.
Link: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp
Ejemplo:

```
var my_td='<td><input value="'+unidad_admin2+'"></td>'
```